# Add new row to DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I searching for a easy method for adding new row to datagrid. So, what I have:

```
dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 4;
int w = 0;
foreach (var item in tInArr)
{...
dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
dataGridView2[0, w].Value = muTat3.ToString();
dataGridView2[1, w].Value = item.ToString();
....
w++;}
```

Where is my mistake? I've read some articles here, but there's no answers.

Comment: Are you getting an index error I presume?

Comment: @AnuragJain it a list of some numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have no datasource, then you can go the following way:

```
  int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
  dataGridView1[0, rowIndex].Value = "value1"; // 0 for first column
  dataGridView1[1, rowIndex].Value = "value2"; // 1 for second column
  rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
  dataGridView1[0, rowIndex].Value = "value3";
  dataGridView1[1, rowIndex].Value = "value4";
```

in your code it should be:

```
// dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 4;  
int w = 0;
foreach (var item in tInArr)
{...
  w = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
  dataGridView2[0, w].Value = muTat3.ToString();
  dataGridView2[1, w].Value = item.ToString();
  ....
  //w++; this is not required
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use datable then iterate your loop like this way :

```
 foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
 {..

     int w =  dataGridView2.Rows.Add();

     dataGridView2[0, w].Value =  rows[0].ToString();
     dataGridView2[1, w].Value = rows[1].ToString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First You create the datatable and then you can set the datasource of datagrid its long but easy to maintain.

like this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Check", typeof(bool));
table.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));


table.Rows.Add(false, "", DateTime.Now);
dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
```